# What will I see from an "obstructed view" balcony cabin on the Regal Princess or Royal Princess?

Tags: cruising

Just looking at the deck plans for these Princess ships, it's hard to tell what the view will be like from what they call an "obstructed view" balcony.

Will the view be very much worse than a normal view balcony?

Comment: If you google the ship name and cabin number, my understanding is that you'll usually find someone who has taken photos and given their experience with that cabin.

Answer (score 3):

Your view will be fine, as long as you're looking off in the distance.  If you try to look down, you will not be able to see, because the lifeboat will be in the way.

[image: Angle of sight for decks 8, 9 and 10 for Regal Princess and Royal Princess]

There's a slideshow with pictures here: https://youtu.be/SyCJ-t_Zjzc